# MongoDB find string match in object value from an array with dynamic object key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i have this document structure where i have dynamic object keys names in field **post** named as dynaimcX for the sake of simplicity.

How can i filter those documents that contains field **image**?

```ts
[
    {
        "_id": "63385ece9801130700fb28e2",
        "post": {
            "dynamicone": [
                {
                    "image": "image1.png"
                }
            ],
            "commments": [
                "Lorem ipsum"
            ]
        },
    },
    {
        "_id": "61702dd8d7bc4106004627f2",
        "post": {
            "dynamictwo": [
                {
                    "image": "image2.png"
                }
            ],
            "commments": [
                "Lorem ipsum"
            ]
        },
    },
    {
        "_id": "61f05a9800b2210700fe3fa3",
        "post": {
            "commments": [
                "Lorem ipsum"
            ]
        },
    },
    {
        "_id": "61701eb47c6bb50700e36c16",
        "post": {
            "commments": [
                "Lorem ipsum"
            ]
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dynamic value is considered an anti-pattern and introduces unnecessary complexity to queries. You can do something much simpler with proper schema:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "post.value": {
    $exists: true
  }
})
```

schema proposed:

```json
 {
    "_id": "63385ece9801130700fb28e2",
    "post": {
      "key": "dynamicone",
      "value": [
        {
          "image": "image1.png"
        }
      ],
      "commments": [
        "Lorem ipsum"
      ]
    },
    
  }
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WkWqeWRpD2D)

---

Here is [another version](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dNYgMReKLi1) that keeps your original schema. You can see it is much more complex as it involves `$objectToArray`

Comment: That's it, amazing response. I've seen ```$objectToArray``` feature but i wasn't able to figure out how to use in my query. As for now this structure is all i have to work, refactor will take time, i'll handle the scenario this way for now but definitely will refactor it. Thank you, you were very helpful.